# Bayesian update (considering normal distributions as model) always decreases the standard deviation

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

I am trying to refine a sensor measurement using Bayes rule to update the sensor value $x$ after consecutive measurements. I model the sensor value with a normal distribution $P(x) = N(x; \mu, \sigma)$. Also the probability density function of the observation given the sensor value $x$ is modeled with a normal distribution $P(x_{obs} | x) \propto N(x_{obs}; x, \sigma_{obs})$; with $\sigma_{obs}$, a standard deviation which changes for each data point.

Using Bayes rule, we have that $ P(x | x_{obs}) \propto P(x_{obs} | x)  P(x)$, and considering that we have normal distributions $P(x | x_{obs})$ is also a normal distribution with standard deviation given by

$\sigma_{new} = \sqrt(\frac{\sigma_{obs}^{2} \sigma^{2} }{ \sigma_{obs}^{2} + \sigma^{2} })$ .

Now I assume that I am applying Bayes rule correctly. However, what troubles me is that regardless on how close each consecutive measurements are to each other, the standard deviation always decreases after each update.

To check this, I have the following code:

```matlab
def compute_var(sigma_1, sigma_2):
    sigma_c = np.sqrt( np.power(sigma_1, 2) * np.power(sigma_2, 2) / (np.power(sigma_1, 2) + np.power(sigma_2, 2)))
    return sigma_c

s = []
q = []
sigma_2 = 3
for sigma_1 in tqdm(np.linspace(0.0001, 10, 1000)):
    s.append(compute_var(sigma_1, sigma_2))
    q.append(compute_var(sigma_1, sigma_2) / np.minimum(sigma_1, sigma_2))

plt.plot(q)
```

[image: evolution of ratio between smallest sigma and updated sigma]

For the problem that I am considering this seems a bit strange behavior. Hence, I have the following questions:

1. am I applying Bayes update rule in a wrong fashion ?
2. if I applying correctly, is my reasoning about the decrease in standard deviation correct? and if I would like to prevent the standard deviation to always decrease, how could I go about that?

Comment: What you are doing is a little unclear; nowhere in your updating expressions do you have any data, or so it seems, so how are you are updating $\mu$ and $\sigma$ based on observed sensor values?   You also have the very unclear expression $P(obs | x) \propto N(x; ...)$, which makes no sense, since the r.h.s. term is the probability of $x$ but the l.h.s. term is the probability of the observation given $x$.  There are other problems, but those will do to start.  You might want to go back to square one with the math or clean up your notation if it's a notation problem.

Comment: @jbowman thanks for your comment. I have tried to clean up as much as possible. I hope it makes more sense now. If you still think I should reconsider the math, some pointers in the good direction could be helpful. Thank you in any case, I appreciate your efforts. Tomas

Comment: In your expression $N(x_{obs}; \mu, \sigma_{obs})$, do you really mean $N(x_{obs}; x, \sigma_{obs})$?  Otherwise, it doesn't look like $P(x_{obs})$ really has $x$ as a parameter.

Comment: @jbowman, yes indeed. I corrected this part.